Image Steganography using DWT and LSB Substitution in Python
I am trying to hide a small text within an image using DWT and subsequent LSB substitution of the data in the LL-Subband. After substition of the data in the LL-Subband in each pixel, when I try to take the DWT of the image that I get after applying IDWT on the new LL-subband coefficients after LSB substitution, I get completely different data which is not correct.
I am attaching the code below for embedding and extraction of the data:
class WaveletBasedAes(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, image_path, secret_message) -> None:
        super().__init__(image_path, secret_message)

    def image_steganography(self):
        gray_image = cv2.imread(self.image_path, 0)
        # encrypted_text = self.aes_encrypt()
        message_bits = ' '.join(bin(ord(b))[2:] for b in self.secret_message)
        wavelet = 'haar'  
        coeffs = dwt2(gray_image,wavelet)
        ll_coeffs = coeffs[0]
        embedded_coeffs = self.embed_message_in_ll(ll_coeffs.copy(), ''.join(message_bits.split()))
        new_coeffs = (embedded_coeffs, coeffs[1])

        # Reconstruct stego-image
        stego_image = self.reconstruct_image(new_coeffs, wavelet)

        return stego_image

    def decrypt_and_extract(self,stego_image_path):
        # Load stego-image
        try:
            stego_image = cv2.imread(stego_image_path, 0)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("Error: Image file not found")
            return None

        # Perform DWT
        wavelet = 'haar'  
        coeffs = dwt2(stego_image, wavelet)
        
        # Extract embedded bits from LL sub-band
        ll_coeffs = coeffs[0]
        extracted_bits = self.extract_message_from_ll(ll_coeffs)


        # Decrypt extracted bits with AES
        message = self.aes_decrypt(bitstring_to_bytes( extracted_bits))

        return message


These are the helper functions embed_message_in_ll() and extract_message_from_ll()
    def embed_message_in_ll(self, ll_subband, message):
        # Flatten the LL subband into a 1D array
        ll_flat = ll_subband.flatten()
        length_of_message_in_bin = ''.join(string_to_binary(str(len(message))).split())
        

        # Check if the message can fit into the LL subband
        if len(message+length_of_message_in_bin)  > len(ll_flat):
            raise ValueError("Message is too long to fit into the LL subband")
        
        # Embed the length of the message into the LL subband
        for i in range(18):
            # Convert the current LL coefficient to binary
            coeff_bin = format(int(ll_flat[i]), '08b')

            # Replace the LSB of the coefficient with the current message bit
            new_coeff_bin = coeff_bin[:-1] + length_of_message_in_bin[i]

            # Convert the new coefficient back to an integer
            new_coeff = int(new_coeff_bin, 2)

            # Replace the original coefficient with the new one
            ll_flat[i] = new_coeff


        # Embed the message into the LSB of the LL subband
        for i in range(len(message)):
            # Convert the current LL coefficient to binary
            coeff_bin = format(int(ll_flat[i+18]), '08b')

            # Replace the LSB of the coefficient with the current message bit
            new_coeff_bin = coeff_bin[:-1] + message[i]

            # Convert the new coefficient back to an integer
            new_coeff = int(new_coeff_bin, 2)

            # Replace the original coefficient with the new one
            ll_flat[i+18] = new_coeff

        # Reshape the flat LL subband back into its original 2D shape
        new_ll_subband = ll_flat.reshape(ll_subband.shape)
        return new_ll_subband
    
    def extract_message_from_ll(self, ll_coeffs):
        # Flatten the LL subband into a 1D array
        ll_flat = ll_coeffs.flatten()
        length_of_message = ''
        for i in range(18):
            # Extract the LSB from the current LL coefficient
            length_of_message += str(int(ll_flat[i]) & 1)


        # Initialize an empty string to hold the extracted bits
        extracted_bits = ''

        # Extract the LSB from each coefficient in the LL subband
        for coeff in ll_flat:
            # Convert the coefficient to binary
            coeff_bin = format(coeff, '08b')

            # Extract the LSB and append it to the extracted bits
            extracted_bits += coeff_bin[-1]

        return extracted_bits

    
    def reconstruct_image(self, coeffs, wavelet):
        return idwt2(coeffs, wavelet=wavelet) 

I am directly stuck after the ll_coeffs=coeffs[0] method, as it gives wrong LL-subband values, which makes it impossible to make sense of the LSB data.
